# Is there a way to use only one p-toast for all messages?

Tags: angular, primeng, toast

I am using primeng p-toast to display messages.

I placed p-toast html in app.component.html

```
<div class="main-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<p-toast position="top-right" key="main"></p-toast>
```

and imported ToastModule and MessageService in a sharedModule so any components can use it.

Tried to display a message using this on many of the child components, but it did not display

```
this.messageService.add({
          key: "main",
          severity: "info",
          detail: "Ready to scan",
        });
```

I still have to add p-toast html in the child's html to make it work.

The child component is loaded thru app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: "catalogs",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./catalog/catalog.module").then((m) => m.CatalogModule)
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Is there a way to declare only one , and child components call on messageService.add can display the message on that p-toast?

Comment: It works for me out ouf the box https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-toast-demo-nfxbfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html

Comment: Sorry, i missed some information.
When the child is loaded via routes, it did not work
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: "catalogs",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./catalog/catalog.module").then((m) => m.CatalogModule),
  }];

Comment: Sorry, i missed some information.
I updated the details @yurzui

Comment: Still works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-toast-demo-nfxbfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It is now working.
I moved ToastModule and MessageService imports from ShareModule to AppModule.
Thanks!

Comment: in case you problem is fixed it 's better to add an answer and explain how did you fixed then mark it as accepted 

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed the problem with the help of @yurzui

Previously, ToastModule and MessageService are imported in SharedModule so that I won't have to repeatedly import stuffs to other modules I created.

I just moved ToastModule and MessageService imports from SharedModule to AppModule
since `<p-toast>` is only in app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

This is probably little late but this is how I implemented global toast in Angular 17.

appConfig.ts

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withComponentInputBinding()), 
    provideAnimations(),
    MessageService,
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule)
  ]
};
```

toast.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToastService {
  TOAST_KEY:string = 'global-toast';
  STICKY:boolean = true;

  constructor(private msgService: MessageService) { }

  async showSuccessToast(summary:string,
                        detail:string): Promise<void> {
    this.showToast(summary,detail,'success');
  }

  async showInfoToast(summary:string,
                        detail:string): Promise<void> {
    this.showToast(summary,detail,'info');
  }
  async showWarnToast(summary:string,
                        detail:string): Promise<void> {
    this.showToast(summary,detail,'warn');
  }

  async showErrorToast(summary:string,
                        detail:string): Promise<void> {
    this.showToast(summary,detail,'error');
  }

  async showToast(summary:string,
                  detail:string,
                  severity:string): Promise<void> {
    this.msgService.add({
      key:this.TOAST_KEY, 
      severity: severity, 
      summary: summary,
      detail: detail, 
      sticky: this.STICKY });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="_header_container">
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
</div>
<div class="_content_container">
    <app-content></app-content>
</div>
<p-toast key="global-toast"></p-toast>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    SidebarComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    ToastModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Root Title';
}
```

toolbar.component.ts

```
constructor(private toastService: ToastService,
          protected route: ActivatedRoute,
          protected router: Router) {}

onClickEvent() {
  this.toastService.showSuccessToast('Success', 'Button clicked.');
}
```

child.component.ts

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute
    private toastService:ToastService) {}

viewDetail() {
  this.toastService.showInfoToast('Info', 'View detail clicked.');
}
```